# change cinema seat color in javafx on every click

Tags: java, javafx

I am making a cinema seat reservation system in JavaFX. I am using buttons as seats.

I want to change it's color when clicked which means seat selected and revert it's color to original color when pressed again which means seat deselected.

I have attached code sample where button's original color is blue and it changes it's color to red when clicked but I also want to change it's color back to blue when clicked again

```
button.setOnAction(event -> {        
       button.setStyle("-fx-background-color: Red");    
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

each time `setOnAction` is invoked you should check if the current style is "Red" and if so change it to "Blue" otherwise if the current style is "Blue" change it to "Red"

in code, it would look like:

```
button.setOnAction(event -> {
     if("-fx-background-color: Red".equals(button.getStyle())){          
         button.setStyle("-fx-background-color: Blue");    
     }else{
         button.setStyle("-fx-background-color: Red");  
     }
});
```

Comment: it worked!!! and I want to add that seat number to an arraylink when it's selected(turns red) and on deselecting it(when turns blue) I want to remove that seat number from arraylink. I hope you will help me here too.

Comment: @irfan seems simple enough, look into the [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) class for the [`add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-E-) and [`remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) methods. once understood think about whether the add call to the list should go inside the `if` or `else` block and conversely should the `remove` call go inside the `if` or `else` block?. you should try to understand the code as that's the best way to learn. good luck.